# STM32F070 EXTI(n) mistriggers

Tags: button, stm32, interrupt

[MCU Sch for button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJaxX.png)

I have 5 buttons which i have mapped to EXTI interrupts.

PA0,PA1,PA2,PA3,PA15

I have observed that when the button on the PA0 is pressed , it invokes EXTI interrupt for PA1 and vice-versa. PA2 and PA3 behave similarly.

Here is the callback function

```
void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_Pin)
{
        if(GPIO_Pin == GPIO_PIN_0)
        {
            val1++;
        }
        if(GPIO_Pin == GPIO_PIN_1)
        {
            val2++;
        }
        if(GPIO_Pin == GPIO_PIN_2)
        {
            val3++;
        }
        if(GPIO_Pin == GPIO_PIN_3)
        {
            val4++;
        }       
        
}
```

Pressing Key0 should only increment val1 , but it increments val2 and vice-versa

Here is the ISR

```
void EXTI0_1_IRQHandler(void)
    {
      /* USER CODE BEGIN EXTI0_1_IRQn 0 */
        /* USER CODE END EXTI0_1_IRQn 0 */
      
      HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(GPIO_PIN_0);
      HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(GPIO_PIN_1);
        
      /* USER CODE BEGIN EXTI0_1_IRQn 1 */
      /* USER CODE END EXTI0_1_IRQn 1 */
    }
```

I have checked noise on the power rail and i see none.
In one version, there was debounce added too (although you cannot see it in the current version)
When I place a breakpoint in the ISR , a false interrupt on PA1 is triggered when the button on PA0 is pressed (val1 should increment, instead val2 increments)
I also tried disabling the Interrupt once it enters the ISR and re-enabling the interrupt in main() after it is processed. But it behaves in the same erratic way.

Can someone point out if there is some mistake in my code or any other issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler` fire the call-back for PA0 at all? What's the value of the `EXTI->PR` register if you break on `HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(GPIO_PIN_0);`?

Stating the obvious, having you checked the button inputs aren't cross-wired?

Comment: `HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler` fire the call-back for PA0 at all?--> **YES** ,          Value of `EXTI->PR` register if you break on `HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(GPIO_PIN_0)` -->  **0x01**                                           having you checked the button inputs aren't cross-wired?---> **YES**

Comment: Sometimes though , even if PA0 is pressed , `EXTI->PR` --> **0x02**  which is the value for PA1

Comment: This might be a hardware problem. How are the buttons connected to uC? Are there pull-up resistors?

Comment: The buttons are connected through wires , and there are pull-up resistors (15K) on the port pin

Comment: Agree with Tagli, in the danger of this being the wrong board... can you post the schematic showing how the button circuit is connected to uC?

Comment: Please check the schematic part in my original post which I have updated.

Comment: How are you connecting the buttons to 'CON2'? Are you connecting one terminal of each button to 'CON2' and the two loose terminals to a common GND?

Comment: _Are you connecting one terminal of each button to 'CON2' and the two loose terminals to a common GND?_  **YES**